# Convert PF syntax from OpenBSD 4.4 to 5.5: "rdr on", "no nat on", "nat on"

Tags: networking, syntax, firewall, nat, openbsd

How do I convert the PF syntax below from OpenBSD 4.4 to OpenBSD 5.5?

```
rdr on $IF_LAN proto tcp from $LAN to $IP_WAN port http -> $WEB_SERV
no nat on $IF_LAN proto tcp from $IF_LAN to $LAN
nat on $IF_LAN proto tcp from $LAN to $WEB_SERV port http -> $IP_LAN
```

Answer (score 0):

use pass in for rdr-to and pass out for nat-to

```
pass in on $IF_LAN proto tcp from $LAN to $IP_WAN port http rdr-to $WEB_SERV
pass out on $IF_LAN proto tcp from $LAN to $WEB_SERV port http nat-to $IP_LAN
```

no nat seems to be a question on design